# ModSecurity - tx variables in CRS

Tags: mod-security

I would like to apply ModSecurity CRS in my project.
However, I have few questions related to this.
Can anybody explain, why the rule:

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@pm nessustest appscan_fingerprint" \
    "phase:2,rev:'2',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',maturity:'9',accuracy:'9',t:none,t:lowercase,block,msg:'Request Indicates a Security Scanner Scanned the Site',logdata:'%{matched_var}',id:'990902',tag:'OWASP_CRS/AUTOMATION/SECURITY_SCANNER',tag:'WASCTC/WASC-21',tag:'OWASP_TOP_10/A7',tag:'PCI/6.5.10',severity:'2',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/AUTOMATION/SECURITY_SCANNER-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}"
```

contains these actions:

```
setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/AUTOMATION/SECURITY_SCANNER-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}
```

Why do we need to put the message in transaction collection? Why do we need to set the anomaly score?
Why do we need to this:

```
setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/AUTOMATION/SECURITY_SCANNER-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}
```

Any info would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,
Maksim

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it.

There are two modes:

1. *Self-contained mode*: when rules just block the request
2. *collaborative mode*: rules block the request, which have big anomaly score